# How to test binary trees in prolog

Tags: prolog, binary-tree

I want to test this prolog program:

#

```
binary_tree(void).

binary_tree(tree(_Element,Left,Right)):-binary_tree(Left),binary_tree(Right).

test(tree(a,tree(b,tree(d,void,void),void),tree(c,void,void))).
```

#

When I execute it with:

```
test(X), binary_tree(X).
```

I get

```
X = tree(a, tree(b, tree(d, void, void), void), tree(c, void, void)).
```

(and I should get "true" instead)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie is right

Answer (score 2):

Who says you should just get `true` instead? Calls to Prolog predicates may succeed or fail. On success, they answer with a variable substitution, as in your case. Your Prolog system's answer says that your test succeeded, as you expected.

You will usually only get `true` if no variable substitution can be given because the query does not contain any variables. If the query fails, you will get `false` or `fail` but no variable substitution.